# Get path and Distance from my current location to user input location

Tags: android, google-maps, location

What i want is that user provide location name from EditText.
Then user click search location button.
Then pin point user input and user's current location and calculate the distance from current location to user searched location and draw line .
I have done following code which only show google map.Yet not included EditText also.
where i have to include to EditText and Button ?

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      package="com.joshclemm.android.tutorial"
      android:versionCode="1"
      android:versionName="1.0">
    <application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
        <activity android:name=".MyMapLocationActivity"
                  android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    <!-- Make sure the uses-library line is inside the application tag -->
    <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />
    </application>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
</manifest>
```

**main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <com.google.android.maps.MapView
        android:id="@+id/mapview"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:apiKey="My Api key"
        android:clickable="true" />

</LinearLayout>
```

**FixedMyLocationoverlay.java**

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.Point;
import android.graphics.Paint.Style;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.location.Location;

import com.google.android.maps.GeoPoint;
import com.google.android.maps.MapView;
import com.google.android.maps.MyLocationOverlay;
import com.google.android.maps.Projection;


public class FixedMyLocationOverlay extends MyLocationOverlay {

    private boolean bugged = false;

    private Drawable drawable;
    private Paint accuracyPaint;
    private Point center;
    private Point left;
    private int width;
    private int height;

    public FixedMyLocationOverlay(Context context, MapView mapView) {
        super(context, mapView);
    }

    @Override
    protected void drawMyLocation(Canvas canvas, MapView mapView,
            Location lastFix, GeoPoint myLocation, long when) {
        if (!bugged) {
            try {
                super.drawMyLocation(canvas, mapView, lastFix, myLocation, when);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // we found a buggy phone, draw the location icons ourselves
                bugged = true;
            }
        }

        if (bugged) {
            if (drawable == null) {

                accuracyPaint = new Paint();
                accuracyPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
                accuracyPaint.setStrokeWidth(2.0f);

                drawable = mapView
                        .getContext()
                        .getResources()
                        .getDrawable(
                                R.drawable.ic_maps_indicator_current_position);
                width = drawable.getIntrinsicWidth();
                height = drawable.getIntrinsicHeight();
                center = new Point();
                left = new Point();
            }

            Projection projection = mapView.getProjection();
            double latitude = lastFix.getLatitude();
            double longitude = lastFix.getLongitude();
            float accuracy = lastFix.getAccuracy();

            float[] result = new float[1];

            Location.distanceBetween(latitude, longitude, latitude,
                    longitude + 1, result);
            float longitudeLineDistance = result[0];

            GeoPoint leftGeo = new GeoPoint(
                    (int) (latitude * 1e6),
                    (int) ((longitude - accuracy / longitudeLineDistance) * 1e6));
            projection.toPixels(leftGeo, left);
            projection.toPixels(myLocation, center);
            int radius = center.x - left.x;

            accuracyPaint.setColor(0xff6666ff);
            accuracyPaint.setStyle(Style.STROKE);
            canvas.drawCircle(center.x, center.y, radius, accuracyPaint);

            accuracyPaint.setColor(0x186666ff);
            accuracyPaint.setStyle(Style.FILL);
            canvas.drawCircle(center.x, center.y, radius, accuracyPaint);

            drawable.setBounds(center.x - width / 2, center.y - height / 2,
                    center.x + width / 2, center.y + height / 2);
            drawable.draw(canvas);
        }
    }
}
```

**MyLocationMapActivity.java**

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.maps.GeoPoint;
import com.google.android.maps.MapActivity;
import com.google.android.maps.MapView;
import com.google.android.maps.MyLocationOverlay;

public class MyMapLocationActivity extends MapActivity {

    private MapView mapView;
    private MyLocationOverlay myLocationOverlay;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.main); 

        mapView = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.mapview);
        mapView.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
        myLocationOverlay = new FixedMyLocationOverlay(this, mapView);
        mapView.getOverlays().add(myLocationOverlay);
        mapView.postInvalidate();
        zoomToMyLocation();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        myLocationOverlay.enableMyLocation();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        myLocationOverlay.disableMyLocation();
    }


    private void zoomToMyLocation() {
        GeoPoint myLocationGeoPoint = myLocationOverlay.getMyLocation();
        if(myLocationGeoPoint != null) {
            mapView.getController().animateTo(myLocationGeoPoint);
            mapView.getController().setZoom(10);
        }
        else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Cannot determine location", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected boolean isRouteDisplayed() {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Help me.

Comment: Does my answer solve your problem? If yes then please kindly make it as answer so that it will help others in future...If you stuck somewhere feel free to ask!! Enjoy coding...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can put EditText & Button inside main.xml also. You just need to get the value from EditText so its on your requirement that where you want to put it. For Direction, I have used the following code in my application and it runs fine.

Here,

saddr = source address(lat,lng)

daddr = destination address(lat,lng)

Note that you can also pass Address string in stead of lat/lng.

```
public void showDirections(View view) {
        final Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,Uri.parse("http://maps.google.com/maps?" + "saddr="+ latitude + "," + longitude + "&daddr=" + latitude + "," + longitude));
        intent.setClassName("com.google.android.apps.maps","com.google.android.maps.MapsActivity");
        startActivity(intent);
    }
```

**Note that i have used the Web Service of Google Maps to display the Direction.**

To calculate distance you have to use the **distanceTo** method which will return you the distance in double.

```
double distance = sourceLocation.distanceTo(destinationLocation);
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: How can I use google map's web service to display direction. 
What are the steps to use it ?  
Please note me down.

Comment: You just need to write the showDirection function. This 3 line are only required. See i have used URL of Google Map in Intent....

Answer (score 1):

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {

GoogleMap map;
ArrayList<LatLng> markerPoints;
TextView tvDistanceDuration;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    tvDistanceDuration = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_distance_time);

    // Initializing
    markerPoints = new ArrayList<LatLng>();

    // Getting reference to SupportMapFragment of the activity_main
    SupportMapFragment fm = (SupportMapFragment)getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);

    // Getting Map for the SupportMapFragment
    map = fm.getMap();

    // Enable MyLocation Button in the Map
    map.setMyLocationEnabled(true);

    // Setting onclick event listener for the map
    map.setOnMapClickListener(new OnMapClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onMapClick(LatLng point) {

            // Already two locations
            if(markerPoints.size()>1){
                markerPoints.clear();
                map.clear();
            }

            // Adding new item to the ArrayList
            markerPoints.add(point);

            // Creating MarkerOptions
            MarkerOptions options = new MarkerOptions();

            // Setting the position of the marker
            options.position(point);

            /**
            * For the start location, the color of marker is GREEN and
            * for the end location, the color of marker is RED.
            */
            if(markerPoints.size()==1){
                options.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_GREEN));
            }else if(markerPoints.size()==2){
                options.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_RED));
            }

            // Add new marker to the Google Map Android API V2
            map.addMarker(options);

            // Checks, whether start and end locations are captured
            if(markerPoints.size() >= 2){
                LatLng origin = markerPoints.get(0);
                LatLng dest = markerPoints.get(1);

                // Getting URL to the Google Directions API
                String url = getDirectionsUrl(origin, dest);

                DownloadTask downloadTask = new DownloadTask();

                // Start downloading json data from Google Directions API
                downloadTask.execute(url);
            }
        }
    });
}

private String getDirectionsUrl(LatLng origin,LatLng dest){

    // Origin of route
    String str_origin = "origin="+origin.latitude+","+origin.longitude;

    // Destination of route
    String str_dest = "destination="+dest.latitude+","+dest.longitude;

    // Sensor enabled
    String sensor = "sensor=false";

    // Building the parameters to the web service
    String parameters = str_origin+"&"+str_dest+"&"+sensor;

    // Output format
    String output = "json";

    // Building the url to the web service
    String url = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/"+output+"?"+parameters;

    return url;
}

/** A method to download json data from url */
private String downloadUrl(String strUrl) throws IOException{
    String data = "";
    InputStream iStream = null;
    HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
    try{
        URL url = new URL(strUrl);

        // Creating an http connection to communicate with url
        urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

        // Connecting to url
        urlConnection.connect();

        // Reading data from url
        iStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();

        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(iStream));

        StringBuffer sb  = new StringBuffer();

        String line = "";
        while( ( line = br.readLine())  != null){
            sb.append(line);
        }

        data = sb.toString();

        br.close();

    }catch(Exception e){
        Log.d("Exception while downloading url", e.toString());
    }finally{
        iStream.close();
        urlConnection.disconnect();
    }
    return data;
}

// Fetches data from url passed
private class DownloadTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String>{

    // Downloading data in non-ui thread
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... url) {

        // For storing data from web service
        String data = "";

        try{
            // Fetching the data from web service
            data = downloadUrl(url[0]);
        }catch(Exception e){
            Log.d("Background Task",e.toString());
        }
        return data;
    }

    // Executes in UI thread, after the execution of
    // doInBackground()
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);

        ParserTask parserTask = new ParserTask();

        // Invokes the thread for parsing the JSON data
        parserTask.execute(result);
    }
}

/** A class to parse the Google Places in JSON format */
private class ParserTask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, List<List<HashMap<String,String>>> >{

    // Parsing the data in non-ui thread
    @Override
    protected List<List<HashMap<String, String>>> doInBackground(String... jsonData) {

        JSONObject jObject;
        List<List<HashMap<String, String>>> routes = null;

        try{
            jObject = new JSONObject(jsonData[0]);
            DirectionsJSONParser parser = new DirectionsJSONParser();

            // Starts parsing data
            routes = parser.parse(jObject);
        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return routes;
    }

    // Executes in UI thread, after the parsing process
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(List<List<HashMap<String, String>>> result) {
        ArrayList<LatLng> points = null;
        PolylineOptions lineOptions = null;
        MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions();
        String distance = "";
        String duration = "";

        if(result.size()<1){
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "No Points", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return;
        }

        // Traversing through all the routes
        for(int i=0;i<result.size();i++){
            points = new ArrayList<LatLng>();
            lineOptions = new PolylineOptions();

            // Fetching i-th route
            List<HashMap<String, String>> path = result.get(i);

            // Fetching all the points in i-th route
            for(int j=0;j<path.size();j++){
                HashMap<String,String> point = path.get(j);

                if(j==0){    // Get distance from the list
                    distance = (String)point.get("distance");
                    continue;
                }else if(j==1){ // Get duration from the list
                    duration = (String)point.get("duration");
                    continue;
                }

                double lat = Double.parseDouble(point.get("lat"));
                double lng = Double.parseDouble(point.get("lng"));
                LatLng position = new LatLng(lat, lng);

                points.add(position);
            }

            // Adding all the points in the route to LineOptions
            lineOptions.addAll(points);
            lineOptions.width(2);
            lineOptions.color(Color.RED);
        }

        tvDistanceDuration.setText("Distance:"+distance + ", Duration:"+duration);

        // Drawing polyline in the Google Map for the i-th route
        map.addPolyline(lineOptions);
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}
}
```